# In Go, how can I reuse a ReadCloser?

Tags: go

I have a http request which I need to inspect the body of. But when I do, the request fails. I'm assuming this had to do with the Reader needing to be reset, but googling along the lines of `go ioutil reset ReadCloser` hasn't turned anything up that looks promising.

`c` is a `*middleware.Context`,
`c.Req.Request` is a `http.Request`, and
`c.Req.Request.Body` is an `io.ReadCloser`

```
contents, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Req.Request.Body)
log.Info("Request: %s", string(contents))
proxy.ServeHTTP(c.RW(), c.Req.Request)
```

Specifically the error I get is `http: proxy error: http: ContentLength=133 with Body length 0`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't reset it, because you've already read from it and there's nothing left in the stream.

What you can do is take the buffered bytes you already have, and replace the Body with a new `io.ReadCloser`

```
contents, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Req.Request.Body)
log.Info("Request: %s", string(contents))
c.Req.Request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(contents))
proxy.ServeHTTP(c.RW(), c.Req.Request)
```